# How can I access Haddock documentation for Plutus?

Tags: plutus, documentation

The link to the Plutus documentation - https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/ - is broken. Is there another way to browse the haddock documentation for the latest version of Plutus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The playground has been discontinued. Haddock can now be accessed at https://input-output-hk.github.io/plutus/master